# Periodogram (Welch) has different levels depending on length of segment/ resolution

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, periodogram

I am trying to compute the PSD of a signal in MATLAB using Welch's periodogram method as shown in the code snippet below.

```
sine = dsp.SineWave('Amplitude',1,'Frequency',10e6,'SampleRate',fs,'SamplesPerFrame',1000000);
y = sine();

nsc = 500000; % 5000 50000
nov = floor(nsc/2);
nff = max(256,2^nextpow2(nsc));

[pxx, f] = pwelch(y,hann(nsc),nov,nff,fs);
pxx = 10*log10(pxx) + 30; % also convert to dBm
plot(f, pxx);

grid on;
xlim([0 20e6]);
xlabel("Frequency (Hz)");
ylabel("PSD (dBm/Hz)");
```

However I get very different power levels depending on the length of the section of data I use which is related to the resolution as shown in the images for $nsc = 5000$ and $50000$ respectively:
[image] [image]

It's very similar to what happens when I use the spectrum analyser and use different resolution bandwidth. With the SA, I typically normalise by subtracting 10log10(RBW).

How should I go about making the PSD from the MATLAB code more consistent? Subtracting $10log_{10}(fs/nsc)$ doesn't seem to be working or am I getting the resolution wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Use the power spectrum instead: `pwelch(y,hann(nsc),nov,nff,fs,'power')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jdip. I was hoping to use the PSD version rather than the 'power' version because I would like to compute a phase noise profile.

Answer (score 5):

The power spectrum measures the distribution of **power vs frequency components**, so its scaling preserves the correct power spectrum peak heights, while the PSD measures the distribution of **power vs unit frequency**, so its scaling preserves broadband power.

The PSD is appropriate if one is interested in consistent **broad-band** power levels. If you want consistent **narrow-band** power levels, you should compute the power spectrum, which uses a different scaling factor. **These are the scaling factors Matlab's `welch` method applies under the hood depending on the `method` specified.**

Denote by $|X|^2$ the frequency averaged Squared Magnitude Spectrum and $w$ the window applied.

- The PSD is: $$\frac{2|X|^2}{f_s \times S_2} \quad \texttt{with} \quad S_2 =
     \sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1} w_i^2$$
- The Power Spectrum is: $$\frac{2|X|^2}{(S_1)^2} \quad \texttt{with} \quad S_1
     = \sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1} w_i$$

Add a little noise to your pure tone, and notice how the noise power stays the same but signal power fluctuates when you change `nsc` with the PSD, and how the opposite is true when using the Power Spectrum:

[image]

To replicate:

```
close all
fs = 20e7;
sine = dsp.SineWave('Amplitude',1,'Frequency',10e6,'SampleRate',fs,'SamplesPerFrame',1000000);
y = sine();
y = y+ randn(length(y),1);

figure(1)
subplot 211
title('psd')
hold on
subplot 212
title('Power spectrum')
hold on
for method = {'psd', 'power'}
    for nsc = [500000, 50000, 5000]
        nov = floor(nsc/2);
        nff = max(256,2^nextpow2(nsc));

        [pxx, f] = pwelch(y,rectwin(nsc),nov,nff,fs, string(method));
        pxx = 10*log10(pxx) + 30; % also convert to dBm
        
        if strcmp(string(method), "psd")
            subplot 211
            ylabel("PSD (dBm/Hz)");
        else
            subplot 212
            ylabel("PS (dBm)");
        end
        plot(f, pxx);
        grid on;
        xlim([0 20e6]);
        xlabel("Frequency (Hz)");
        
    end
end
legend('nsc = 500000', 'nsc = 50000', 'nsc = 5000');
```